# Expression: map/set iterators incompatible assert on map creation

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, assert

I have code that causes the assertion failure. When I leave only the one item (pair) in the map the code works, but two or more triggers the error. I traced it under debugger and saw that all the instances of involved types (I mean pair, set) are created properly. But when the flow comes to semicolon that encloses the table definition I get this assertion failure pops up.

basic.hpp

```
namespace ccnet
{

enum class master_command_code 
{
  RESET                   = 0x30,
  GET_STATUS              = 0x31
};

enum class slave_message_type 
{
  GENERAL = 1, // response to a master command bearing data
  ACK     = 0,
  NACK    = 0xff,
  ILLEGAL = 0x30,
  UNKNOWN = 2 // if we are unable to identify the data
};

/** Slave message set. */
typedef std::set<slave_message_type> slave_messsage_set_type;

const slave_messsage_set_type& allowed_reply(master_command_code code);
} // namespace ccnet
```

basic.cpp

```
const ccnet::slave_messsage_set_type& ccnet::allowed_reply(master_command_code code)
{
  typedef map<master_command_code, slave_messsage_set_type> master_slave_table_map;

  static const master_slave_table_map table =
    {
      // applicable in all states
      { master_command_code::RESET,
        { slave_message_type::ACK, slave_message_type::NACK } },

      { master_command_code::GET_STATUS,
        { slave_message_type::GENERAL, slave_message_type::NACK } }
    }; // <-- assert here

  const auto it = table.find(code);
  if (it == table.end())
  {
    throw std::runtime_error(
      "Unregistered/unimplemented master command code specified");
  }

  return it->second;
}
```

I have no idea why it happens, the code looks fine.
I use MSVC-12. It's not the thread concurrency problem, I've checked. 1. It's static; 2. I put it at first line of main() and have the issue. (

Comment: If you could update your post to include the *actual* enum's and proper surrounding namespace decls, it would be monumentally helpful. as presented it is somewhat spaghetti.

Comment: It might help if you could create a [Minimum Complete Verifable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us. It shoudln't be too hard, as you've basically only elided a few details. If the example compiles and runs fine, then the issue probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: I've made changes as you asked

Comment: Thanks. I threw out the exception class not included in favor of just an std::invalid_argument. Should make no different to your actual problem, which I cannot replicate using clang 3.4. Sorry I don't have a VS12 install handy to test that config. It also seems ok with gcc [(see it live on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/dVvdSG) and [on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9c97b9c0ab7b62b)).

Comment: Yes, the issue appears before the throw line.

Comment: Well, [at least according to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080108/visual-studio-2012-update-3-initializer-list-variadic-templates) you're apparently hosed if you're using VS2012 and set initializer lists. [Apparently they're not fulfilled until VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368(v=vs.120).aspx). Darn it all, I hate being the bringer of bad news. Sorry man.

Comment: msvc-12 is vs2013, but it seems you are quite right anyway

Comment: @Rook I've made it complete

Comment: So I see. It is possible to reduce it to a 10-line minimal example, but seeing as it has already been established that its a compiler issue, it probably isn't worth it. I can replicate the assertion under VS2013 express, and the same code works fine under GCC 4.7 and 4.8.

Comment: Is it possible to use 3rd party toolset within VS2013? As I know MS it should be impossible. ps.: Waiting for JetBrains IDEA for C++.

Comment: Second update resolves the issue. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42666